# Bash exec expansion param

Tags: bash, exec

I try to use in my bashrc:

```
something(){
  cmd="sudo $@"
  ...
  exec {*}$cmd
}
```

because sudo with: `eval exec "$cmd"` close my session after the command, but the expansion operator `{*}` did not works

but the command is failed

```
bash: exec: {*}sudo: not found
```

do you have any ideas about that? And How can i keep the sudo session active after that ?

*edit*: how to `exec` a `sudo` command in the same shell ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you aware of what the `exec` command does -- specifically, that it replaces the current shell with the other program, effectively exiting the shell (which seems to be what you're trying to avoid)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```bash
something(){
  cmd="sudo ${@}"
  ...
  exec ${cmd}
}
```

Update :

Try using `-S` option with `sudo` to read the password from standard input, and `-s` option to run a shell with elevated privileges:

```bash
something() {
  cmd="sudo -S -s ${@}"
  ...
  echo "$PASSWORD" | $cmd
}
```

Comment: i have the same result as `eval exec "$cmd"` My session is closed after that because of `sudo` probably

Comment: Ok thanks, but that's not exactly my problem because i have a NOPASSWD on my sudoers.

I just need stay in the same shell after the command

Comment: Did you try `-s`?

Comment: Yes with cmd ="sudo -s $@" It's ask me the password and the shell is closing. 
With cmd ="sudo -S $@" the shell is just closing.
The password is not needed and the shell still disapear

Comment: i try different sudo option without success

Comment: Hmm... One solution is to use the `sudo -v` command before running the `sudo` command, which will update the user's cached credentials and keep the session open

Comment: `something() { sudo -v cmd="sudo $@" $cmd }`